# Map on an initial undefined value

Tags: reactjs

Is there anything in REACT like in Angular where you can make a nullable type? In angular you would do something like crawlList?.jobsList

```
{crawlList.jobsList.map(crawl => (
   <div>test</div>
))}
```

The challenge is I set jobsList dynamically on a click, but on initial load above will fail with "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Or du you need to initialize the data?

Comment: crawlList.jobsList = []

Comment: So the answer is you need to initialize all the elements in the array? And dont have the option like in Angular?

Comment: Yes, you would always get the error, it's pure javascript execution. One other option you have is to do this: `{crawlList.jobsList && crawlList.jobsList.map(crawl => (<div>test</div>)}`. This would ensure that the jobList is initialized before doing a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. So if jobsList doesn't exist, you will map over empty array

```
{(crawlList.jobsList || []).map(crawl => (
     <div>test</div>
))}
```